# How to "gödelize" the number 11?

Tags: number-theory, proof-explanation, proof-theory

I'm trying to understand the method Gödel described in his famous paper "Über formal unentscheidbare Sätze der Principia Mathematica und verwandter Systeme I" and I don't understand many things about it right now, but the most prominent question on my mind is:

How to gödelize the number 11?

On page 11, he defines $R(x) \equiv 2^x$, for for example 100 can be formalized  as $2^{100}$. This is bijective. You can always get the 100 "back". I understand this as a special case of the more general function of gödelization:

$\text{prim}(\text{pos}_1)^{\text{number}_1} \times \text{prim}(\text{pos}_2)^{\text{number}_2} \times \text{prim}(\text{pos}_3)^{\text{number}_3} \times \dots $

where of course the position is 1 and therefore, $\text{prim}(1) = 2$, and the number in the special case of $R(x)$ being only 2, because there is only one position in the resulting formula.

Now my problem.

On page 8 he defines some "constants", e.g. 11 = "(", 13 = ")" etc. And he frequently uses these numbers, too. For example on page 11, § 10, where he says

$E(x) \equiv R(11) \times x \times R(13)$

which puts the number into brackets (11 and 13).

But how does he distinguish between the literal number 11 and a bracket, when "de-gödelizing" (e.g. interpretating) the number again?

This is very unclear to me and in the whole paper, I cannot find anything regarding this issue.

Is it that, as said in § 17, a number is not specified as a real "number", but more as "5 = fffff0", i.e. successions of the successor-function on 0?

(Remember: I am only a layman and this might very well be only my missunderstanding)

Comment: I would have thought positive integers were not encoded directly, but instead for example eleven would first be $SSSSSSSSSSS0$ which following his code gets encoded to eleven exponents of $3$ followed by one exponent of $1$

Comment: Yes, thanks, this is what I notice and also edited in the question and this solves everything! Thanks!

Comment: FWIW I would strongly recommend avoiding Godel's original paper - there are many modern presentations which are much, much better (as is generally true of any theorem: our understanding and explanations get better over time). Personally I recommend the one in Boolos, Burgess, and Jeffrey's book, but it's only one of many.

Answer (score 2):

Everything does indeed do double-duty (or more). A priori, "$11$" is (say) both a number and the code of some formula. But this isn't actually an issue: note that "the formula with Godel number $11$" makes perfect sense even if we have many different things we associate to $11$.

What we have to do is carefully reason about each "layer" of the translation. For example, when we say "the length function of formulas is representable in $T$" *(where $T$ is our theory in question - originally PM, but in modern presentations PA or a variant)* what we mean is that there is a formula $\varphi$ such that for every formula $\psi$ with Godel number $n$ and length $k$ we have

> $T$ proves $\forall x(\varphi(\underline{n},x)\iff x=\underline{k})$

(where "$\underline{i}$" is the numeral associated to the number $i$: e.g. $\underline{2}$ is the string of symbols "$S(S(0))$").

---

Note that this isn't actually weird at all. For example, a computer program (in your favorite language) "is" just a meaningless string of symbols, and we can talk about that string as just a string or as a program. In the same way, we can talk about a number as just a number or as a code for a formula. The whole idea of *compiling* relies on this semantic overloading, and indeed one of Godel's key insights was that this overloading *isn't* actually a problem.